# gTEHbBBl_dY: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

Tags: youtube-dl

I tried getting a simple audio file using this chunk of code off the terminal:

```
 youtube-dl -f bestaudio https://youtu.be/gTEHbBBl_dY
```

it's the simplest yt-dl formula ever and here's what I got.
[youtube] gTEHbBBl_dY: Downloading webpage

```
ERROR: gTEHbBBl_dY: YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
```

so yea...I saw a lot of answers on stack itself but none of them worked for me.
pls help, I'm not a pro yet with homebrew tools.

Comment: (I'd be surprised if tag *homebrew* applied.) Shall I consider "yt-bl" a tool used *in* programming? How is the question implied above [on-topic with stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @greybeard sry will try my best to be more on-point...but do uk how to tackle this?

Comment: I'm no AV down-loader to speak off. From the manuals: *If an audio-only stream is not available, exclude `-f bestaudio`*. ("extract audio" seems to be `-x`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry again, will try to ask better questions!

Comment: If *Unable to extract video data* seems to have been due to omitting `-x`, consider answering your own question.

Comment: To make sure that it's been resolved right?

Comment: Building confidence in an approach before presenting it as a solution sounds prudent. I give myself some leeway in comments, little in answers.

Comment: Is your youtube-dl up-to-date?

Comment: @CForce99 yes it is

Comment: I had the same issue when i was trying to download a video lately and i just tried again and it worked. Not sure why though.

Comment: k For some reason I had to reinstall home-brew itself...the home-brew update didn't install all the dependencies for Big Sur so I did it again and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract audio instead of `-f` to format it to bestaudio

```
youtube-dl -x
```

Comment: can you please explain the meaning ofeach flag to make your answer more usefull and informative